# jquery calculating div offset and bounding based on mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adapting a demo of an image zoom ([my CodePen for it is here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqJZMm)) but one hurdle I've come up against is trying to stop the magnifying glass .mag-glass div from moving when it hits the edge of the .magnify parent div (like in [this MagicZoom example](https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoom/modules/prestashop/)). The .mag-glass position is set in CSS based off the offset position of the mouse in relation to .magnify. I'm just having trouble figuring out exactly how the if statement around

```
$("#"+div+" .mag-glass").css({left: px, top: py});
```

needs to go so that .mag-glass doesn't extend outside .magnify.

Thanks for any help, I'm finding mouse positioning to be the most frustrating part of Javascript right now!

Answer (score 0):

Just check that it doesn't exceed all 4 bounds of the parent `div` (and reset it if it does). As an example:

```
var offset_top = $( '.mag-glass' ).offset().top,
    bound_top = $( '#img1' ).offset().top;

if (offset_top < bound_top) {
    $( '.mag-glass' ).css('top', bound_top);
}
```

Do this for each boundary (e.g. left, right, top, bottom).